# Setting Default font size in an RTF file

Tags: rtf, file-handling

Is there any Command in C through which i can set a particular font size of a **.RTF** file while creating a file.
Actually what i am doing is i am creating a file on Pen drive using usb Host interface with LPC2468.I am using File handling Commands for creating the file.When i open a file after creating it,i have to change the font size to view it properly.

Comment: no, there is not a command in C to do this. You can grok the rtf-format and do the adjustment yourself (fread(), change(), fwrite()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C is only a langauge, and doesn't have a notion of fonts, windows, or whatever other GUI elements may exists. How to set a font is heavily depending on the operating system, resp. the framework you are working with.
So such a question can only be answered in the context of a particular framework